# How to read a line of a text file into an array using c# and then get element by index

Tags: c#

I am trying to read the last line of a text file into an array so that I am able to get a specific element of the array by index, but I am having trouble doing this as 1 line in my text file has many elements that need to go into the array as opposed to there being 1 element per line, so for reference my text file line structure would be like so: `element1,element2,element3`... It is similar in structure to that of a csv file.

My code so far that is not working:

```
string lastline = System.IO.File.ReadLines(myfilepath).Last();
string[] id = new string[](lastline.Split(','));
```

Then after inserting the line to my array I would like to pull an element of the array by the index, for example I want to pull `element2` from the array and assign it to `var item2`, but am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: If `id[index]` does not do the job, I have not understood what you want.

Comment: string.Split already returns an array of the splitted strings. There is no need to _new string[]_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question completely, but getting single string from a string array by index:

```
string lastline = System.IO.File.ReadLines(myfilepath).Last();
string[] id = lastline.Split(',');

//string result = id[index];
/* Better way */
string result = id.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
```

Where `index` is the zero-based index of the items. So, the first string's index would be 0, next 1 etc. Thanks to Steve for pointing out the error in creating the array and the hint to avoid `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
The method `ElementAtOrDefault(index)` will return the element at index, or if the index is out of range, return a default element, which in this case is an empty `string`.

Comment: Thanks Sami! it works, appreciate the quick response. I'll accept the answer when the timer allows me to.

Comment: Another thing to add to your answer is a warning about the IndexOutOfRangeException that is so common in this kind of code (and an example of to avoid it)

Comment: The only  downside with this is if the file is large you'll have to read the whole thing into memory just to get the last line.